# Joda-Time : equivalent of new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()?

Tags: java, jodatime

Equivalent of following methods in [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

**[DateFormatSymbols](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)** [**#getMonths()**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths%28%29)

```
/**
 * Gets month strings. For example: "January", "February", etc.
 * @return the month strings.
 */
public String[] getMonths()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joda actually provides a method to access this data:[DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getDateFormatSymbols%28java.util.Locale%29) in Joda 2.0. I don't believe Joda is trying to replace that method.